# Restarting VM Using Powershell

Tags: c#, powershell

I am trying to restart a VM using powershell in C#.

First i am trying to run the GET-VM command. It is giving an exception at line:

```
PSSnapInInfo psinfo = runspaceConfig.AddPSSnapIn("System.Management.Automation", out snapEx);
```

in below given code. Can someone tell me where i am doing it wrong.

> Exception Message : No snap-ins have been registered for Windows PowerShell version 2

My Code :

```
Command command = new Command("Get-VM");
            command.Parameters.Add("Name", "PIE01010299");
            RunspaceConfiguration runspaceConfig = RunspaceConfiguration.Create();
            PSSnapInException snapEx = null;
            PSSnapInInfo psinfo = runspaceConfig.AddPSSnapIn("System.Management.Automation", out snapEx);
            Runspace runSpace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace(runspaceConfig);
            runSpace.Open();
            Pipeline pipeline = runSpace.CreatePipeline();

            pipeline.Commands.Add(command);
            Collection<PSObject> output = pipeline.Invoke();
            runSpace.Close();
            foreach (PSObject psObject in output)
            {
               Console.WriteLine(psObject.ToString());
            }
```

Answer (score 1):

`System.Management.Automation` is not a snapin.  It is the core PowerShell engine assembly.  It is loaded by default because your C# project needs to reference that assembly.  You probably want to import the `Hyper-V` module e.g.:

```
pipeline.Commands.AddCommand("Import-Module").AddArgument("Hyper-V");
pipeline.Invoke();
pipeline.Clear();
```

Or use the `InitialSessionState.ImportPSModule` method and then associate that with the runspace.